# C# delegate called twice?

Tags: c#, prism, prism-5

I have created an output window where multiple events are subscribed to using Prism's `EventAggregator`. So far the constructor is handling two different events:

```
public OutputWindowView(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
{
    eventAggregator.GetEvent<LoginStatusEvent>().Subscribe(trackLogin, true);
    eventAggregator.GetEvent<ConsoleMessageEvent>().Subscribe(trackMessage, true);

    this.InitializeComponent();
}
```

Both events target the same UI component via `SetText` method:

```
private void trackLogin(LoginStatus s)
{
    SetText("Connected: " + s.IsConnected.ToString());
}

private void trackMessage(string s)
{
    SetText(s);
}
```

I am trying to create a delegate to avoid thread errors.

```
private delegate void SetOutputText(string content);

private void SetText(string content)
{

    Trace.WriteLine("===== SetText =====");

    var text = content + Environment.NewLine;

    if (this.txtOutput.Dispatcher.CheckAccess() == false)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("->CheckAccess > false");
        SetOutputText _output = new SetOutputText(SetText);
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(_output, text);
    }
    else
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("->CheckAccess > true");
        this.txtOutput.Text += text;
    }

}
```

The output hover is:

```
===== SetText =====
->CheckAccess > false
===== SetText =====
->CheckAccess > true
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
===== SetText =====
->CheckAccess > false
```

OR

```
===== SetText =====
->CheckAccess > true
```

but it seems to be called twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe on the UI thread by passing `ThreadOption.UIThread` like this

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent<ConsoleMessageEvent>().Subscribe(trackMessage, ThreadOption.UIThread, true);
```

or even simpler, bind to a property on your viewmodel and you're done, because `INotifyPropertyChanged` events are marshalled to the UI thread automatically.

Comment: Thank you, can you expand on your second point about biding to a property? I am new to C#.

Comment: Normally, especially in the context of prism, you have a view with a view model as data context, and the view model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` (through deriving from `BindableBase` in prism), and you can change properties on the view model from any thread and the view will be updated accordingly. Too much for a comment here, I suppose, you best google for wpf databinding, mvvm, look at the prism examples documentation to get to know the concepts.